# Trying to delete certain css elements from style

Tags: css, regex

I am trying to delete the some elements from the html style="" attribute.

```
<div style="color: red; background: #000; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0;">Hey</div>
```

I want to cut this HTML so it will delete 
position element, and background element.

Example:

```
<div style="color: red; top:0; left: 0;">Hey</div>
```

How can I do that on Regex?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why RegEx for this? Can't you edit the source files, or override the styles with CSS?

Comment: Also: please retag your question with the language you intend to run the regex from (js? php?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple regex could be:

```
/background:.*?;|position:.*?;/
```

If you'd like to check only inside the style attribute in a tag, try the following PHP test code:

```
<?php
$str = '<div style="color: red; background: #000; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0;">Hey</div>';
echo preg_replace('/(<.*?style=.*?)background:.*?;|position:.*?;(.*?")/','$1$2',$str);
?>
```

You also asked to match the case when the attribute doesn't have a semicolon (unique attribute, last attribute). To match the case without semicolon, we should assume that is either the only attribute or is the last one. In both cases we'll have the following regexes working:

```
position:[^;]*?("|')
background:[^;]*?("|')
```

Basically, I'm asking to match the keyword `position:` or `background:` followed by any char **except** the semicolon, repeated zero or more times until a quote (single or double) is found.

This covers the case we called "without semicolon".

The following code should be working for all cases, it's not optimized and is only for clarity and example. It consist of a chain of calls:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<.*?style.*?)(position:[^;]*?)("|\')/','$1$3',$str);
$str = preg_replace('/(<.*?style.*?)(background:[^;]*?)("|\')/','$1$3',$str);
$str = preg_replace('/(<.*?style.*?)(position:.*?;)(.*?")/','$1$3',$str);
$str = preg_replace('/(<.*?style.*?)(background:.*?;)(.*?")/','$1$3',$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: It will delete all of the background:; and position:; even inside the div... I want it to check only inside the Style attribute. even if theres no semicolon sign (Last element or single element doesn't always have.)

Comment: I updated my answer.. is it what you were asking? Well.. the semicolon.. uhm. I'm working on it.

Comment: getting ccloser now it doesn't delete the position element if you put the background element after the position element. for Ex: $str = '<div style="color: red; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; background: #000;">absdf</div>';

 and the semicolon is still a problem. :\

Comment: what about now? I tried to cover all the cases. I also added some round brackets to avoid the attribute ordering problem

Comment: for some reason it's only deleting the background element.

Comment: well.. I changed slightly the calls, and splitted them in two parts each. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

try something like (untested though, so not quite sure wether the expressions are correct, though it should give you enough leadway to solve the rest of the problem)

```
<?php

$pattern = array();
$replacement = array();

$pattern[0] = '/position: [a-zA-Z]+;/';
$pattern[1] = '/background: #[a-zA-Z0-9]+;/';

$replacement[0] = '';
$replacement[1] = '';

$input_html = '<div style="color: red; background: #000; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0;">Hey</div>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input_html);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
$tag = '<div style="color: red; background: #000; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0;">Hey</div>';

$tag = preg_replace('/background:\s?#[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,6};\s?/', '', $tag);
```

that would only be for the background attribute, you would then do another for the color attribute.

```
$tag = preg_replace('/position:\s?[a-zA-Z];\s?/', '', $tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future, you could try to use [Chirpy - VS Add In For Handling Js, Css, DotLess, and T4 Files](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) or similar apps, try googling CSS combine/compress, they regroup all your repeated selectors and stuff.

Also I recommend to use a linked css file, that way you can organize your classes much better